# Why does screen reader read one RadioButton but skips over the rest?

Tags: react-redux, accessibility

I am trying to understand how screen reader works so I can make all my react components screen reader accessible.

So I have a component that takes credit card payments, it reads the credit card radio button selected and all its content, but when you tab to the gift card radio button, or try to, it skips all the other radio buttons and goes straight to the radio button for shipping.

Why does it do this?

Here is the code:

```
return (
      <div className="payment-type summary">
        {isCCAllowed &&
        <div className="payment-choice">
           <RadioButton
              type="radio"
              name="type"
              value={PaymentTypeEnum.CREDIT_CARD}
              checked={this.state.type === PaymentTypeEnum.CREDIT_CARD}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
            <h4 className="inline description payment-option h5">{PaymentHelper.getCreditCardChoiceTitle(this.state.paymentCardTypes)}</h4>
          </RadioButton>
          {PaymentHelper.getPaymentIconsStripe(this.state.paymentCardTypes)}
        </div>
        }
        {displayCC &&
          <div className="cc-accordion-container">
            <PaymentMethodsFromWallet
              paymentCardTypes={this.state.paymentCardTypes}
              onFormCompleted={this.handlePaymentCompleted}
              onFormInvalid={this.handlePaymentInvalid}
              exteralErrors={this.props.paymentTypeErrors}
              onExternalErrorsResolved={this.props.handlePaymentTypeExternalErrorsResolved}
              revalidate={this.props.revalidate}
              onRevalidateComplete={this.props.onRevalidateComplete}
            />
          </div>
        }
        {isGCAllowed &&
        <div className="payment-choice">
          <RadioButton
            type="radio"
            name="type"
            value={PaymentTypeEnum.GIFT_CARD}
            checked={this.state.type === PaymentTypeEnum.GIFT_CARD}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
            <h4 className="description payment-option h5">Disney Gift Card</h4>
          </RadioButton>
          {PaymentHelper.getPaymentIcon(PaymentTypeEnum.GIFT_CARD)}
        </div>
        }
```

The above code is for one component of PaymentType.js

I am using both ChromeVox and Mac VoiceOver and get the same behavior. I do not see any difference in the code itself. So why does it skip over the rest of the radio buttons and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without react, tabbing for radio buttons is based on the button *group*, not each individual button.

You tab to the button group, then use the arrow keys to move among the buttons in the group.

Check the behavior of this simple sample — you'll tab to each of the checkboxes, but only to the first or the currently selected radio button.  Try using both tabs and arrows like this with your own existing markup, and see how the screen reader behaves.

```css
div { margin: 1em; }
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

```html
<div id="checks" style="background-color:lightyellow;border:1px solid black;">
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="one"> something one </label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="two"> something two </label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="three"> something three </label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="four" checked> something four </label></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="radios1" style="background-color:lightgreen;border:1px solid black;">
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="set-one" value="A"> One A </label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="set-one" value="B"> One B </label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="set-one" value="C"> One C </label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="set-one" value="D"> One D </label></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="radios2" style="background-color:lightgreen;border:1px solid black;">
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="set-two" value="W"> Two W </label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="set-two" value="X"> Two X </label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="set-two" value="Y"> Two Y </label></li>
        <li><label><input type="radio" name="set-two" value="Z"> Two Z </label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good example to show keyboard navigation but do not follow the above pattern for screen readers because it's missing all the associations of the labels with the `<input>` fields.  All the text for the checkboxes and radio buttons should have a `<label for="someID">` around them, with *"someID"* pointing to the ID of the respective <input> for the checkbox or radio button.  It's hard to format it nicely in a comment, but essentially `<input type="radio" name="set-one" value="A" id="radio1"><label for="radio1">One A</label>`

Comment: The WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices document gives guidance for this: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#radiobutton

Comment: @slugolicious - true, and I do all those things in real life. I was just trying to demonstrate normal tabbing, which OP didn't seem to know.  I'll edit when I get some time and add a 2nd, more complete example. (cheers  brennanyoung too, I refer to that page often)

Comment: @StephenP, I figured you did, but lots of people copy/paste code examples as is without looking carefully at it so I just wanted to point out that the labels were not associated with the widgets.  And +1 on the recommendation for the authoring practice, brennanyoung.  It's my "bible".